# In R Shiny, how to resolve Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, modal-dialog

In running the below MWE code, when the user goes to the "Liability Module" tab a default value table/plot correctly appears in the main panel. When the user clicks on the "Input Liabilities" action button in the sidebar panel a modal dialogue box pops up where the user can change model inputs (only the first row "A" of the matrix input grid is operational in this MWE). When the user makes a change to the matrix input grid in the modal dialogue box, the table/plot in the main panel correctly updates to reflect this input change. So this works as intended -- except for the data frame size quirk noted below.

When that "Input Liabilities" action button is clicked, an error flashes by in the main panel for a moment until the values table is rendered (and when rendered it is correct). And in the R Studio console, the following message pops up: "Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 60, 0". Bottom left hand corner of image at the bottom shows this console message.  (Note that in this image example, row A of matrix input grid has been manually changed when running the App from 0.2 to 0.23 and in the background you can see the main panel data table values correctly reflect this 0.23 for all 60 periods --- so this works as intended, except that I'd like to remove any error messages so this operates cleanly). How do I eliminate this date frame error?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w,main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b",col="blue",pch=19,cex=1.25)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                        style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
      # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
        tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   button2('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                   button2('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row
                 
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 
                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  
  yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        actionButton('showLiabilityGrid','Input Liabilities',style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'),
        setShadow(id='showLiabilityGrid'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below defines the vectorsAll object before user clicks on actionButton "Input Liabilities" ---->
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$showLiabilityGrid)){df <- NULL}
    else {
      if(input$showLiabilityGrid < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
      else {
        req(yield())
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <-
                 tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(yield(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix1Input("base_input"),
                 div(style = "margin-top: 0px"),
                 useShinyjs(),
               ) # close modalDialog
               ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Below is the final debugged MWE, after correcting an error in plotting the data:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyWidgets)

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){plot(w,main=x,xlab=y,ylab=z,type="b",col="blue",pch=19,cex=1.25)}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                        style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
      # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
        tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   button2('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                   button2('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row
                 
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 
                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  
  yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        actionButton('showLiabilityGrid','Input Liabilities',style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'),
        setShadow(id='showLiabilityGrid'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below defines the vectorsAll object before user clicks on actionButton "Input Liabilities" ---->
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$showLiabilityGrid)){df <- NULL}
    else {
      if(input$showLiabilityGrid < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
      else {
        req(input$base_input)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <-
                 tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(plot(vectorsAll()[,1],sapply(vectorsAll()[,2], function(x)gsub("%", "", x)) )) # << Per YBS solution Aug 27, 2021
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  observeEvent(input$showLiabilityGrid,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix1Input("base_input"),
                 div(style = "margin-top: 0px"),
                 useShinyjs(),
               ) # close modalDialog
               ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent

}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `vectorsAll` change `req(yield())` to `req(input$base_input)`.

Here is that part of the code -

```
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$showLiabilityGrid)){df <- NULL}
    else {
      if(input$showLiabilityGrid < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
      else {
        req(input$base_input)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,Yld_Rate = pct(yield()[,2]))
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  })
```